# DesignTime support for SharePoint 2007 Application Pages in VS2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, design-time, applicationpage

Is there design time support in VS2008 for SharePoint Application Pages?

I've wrote an SPService and I want to develop an UI for the properties
who are necessary for running this SPService. But I can't manage to get
design time support in VS2008. I'm creating an custom ASPX which inherits
from GlobalAdminPage and has the "_admin/admin.master" masterpage.

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use SharePoint Designer?

The admin.master file is in the 12 hive under 12\TEMPLATE\ADMIN\admin.master. You could copy that into an _admin folder in your Visual Studio project. But then you'll need to resolve the broken _controltemplates references with files found in 12\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES. If it's an option, instead of trying to duplicate SharePoint Designer's functionality in Visual Studio, you'd probably be better off just using SharePoint Designer.

Comment: I've also tried that before I posted the question, I should have mention it. Sorry. The same errors pop-up in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: What exactly is the error that you get in SPD? Also, if you are not already, try MasterPageFile="~/_admin/admin.master". That seems to be the pattern for most of the aspx pages in the ADMIN directory.